# Guest user invitation via direct access not working

Tags: external-sharing, guest-access

I added an external user into the folder permission via advanced settings. The user receive an invite. When user clicks on the invite he gets asked to choose org account or Microsoft account or create Microsoft account.

If user selects org account, then it says user isn't part of the AD and must be first added as a guest user. How to fix this?